# How to prevent the shiny app from crashing

Tags: r, shiny

I have a functioning shiny here, which is using "shinymeta" to extract the R-code from the shiny-script, so the user can generate the same output being generated in the shiny, even outside the shiny.

However, when you click on the "show code" button, before generating a plot, or after clicking on the reset button to delete the plot, and then clicking on the "show code" button the app will crash.
so My question is, how can I make the app, "stupid proof" so if the user, clicks on the "show code" button, and there is no code to show the app won't crash?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(shinymeta)
library(shinyjs)

dataset <- mtcars

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  headerPanel("Mtcars"),
  sidebarPanel(sliderInput('sampleSize', 'Sample Size', min=10, max=nrow(dataset),
                           value=min(10, nrow(dataset)), step=5, round=0),
               selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset)),
               selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),
               selectInput('color', 'Color', c('None', names(dataset))),
               checkboxInput('smooth', 'Smooth'),
               selectInput('facet_row', 'Facet Row', c(None='.', names(dataset))),
               selectInput('facet_col', 'Facet Column', c(None='.', names(dataset))),
               hr(),
               checkboxInput("plotly1", "Interactive plot!",value = FALSE, width=140),
               uiOutput("graghbutton"),
               actionButton("reset", "Reset")
               
               
  ),
  mainPanel(
    outputCodeButton(plotOutput('plot')),
    hr(),
    hr(),
    conditionalPanel("input.plotly1 === true", outputCodeButton(plotlyOutput("plot2"))),
    verbatimTextOutput("code")
    
  )
))


server<- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dataset <- metaReactive( { mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), ..(input$sampleSize)),] }) 
  
  
  
  
  output$graghbutton <- renderUI({
    actionButton("plotxxx", "Plot!")
    
  })
  
  
  gragh <- metaReactive2({
    req(input$plotxxx)
    
    p <- isolate(metaExpr({
      
      ggplot(..(dataset()), aes_string(..(input$x), ..(input$y))) + geom_point() }))
    
    
    
    
    if (input$color != 'None')
      p <- isolate(metaExpr({
        
        ..(p) + aes_string(color=..(input$color))
        
        
      }))
    
    
    facets <- isolate(metaExpr({
      paste(..(input$facet_row), '~', ..(input$facet_col))
      
      
      
    }))
    
    if (facets != '. ~ .')
      p <- isolate(metaExpr({
        ..(p) + facet_grid(..(facets))
      }))

    
    
    if (input$smooth)
      p <- isolate(metaExpr({
        ..(p) + geom_smooth()
        
      }))
    
    
    p
    
    
    
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plotxxx, {
    req(input$plotxxx)
    output$plot <- metaRender2(renderPlot, {
      isolate(metaExpr({
        ..(gragh())
        
        
      })
      
      
      
      
      
      )
    })
    
    
  })
  
  
  output$plot2 <- metaRender(renderPlotly, {
    ggplotly(..(gragh()))
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_output_code, {
    code <- expandChain(quote(library(ggplot2)), output$plot())
    displayCodeModal(code)
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plot2_output_code, {
    code <- expandChain(quote(library(ggplot2)), output$plot2())
    displayCodeModal(code)
    
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plotxxx, {
    output$code <- renderPrint({
      req(input$plotxxx)
      isolate(expandChain(output$plot(),
                          output$plot2()
                          
                          
      ))
    })
    
    
    
    
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      
    })
    
    output$code <- renderPrint({
      
    })
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: First, you should likely know what the error is before blindly ignoring it. If it is indeed what you expect, you can use `tryCatch` (or just `try`), perhaps `outputCodeButton(tryCatch(plotOutput('plot'),error=function(e)NULL))` (untested).

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the comment, I get this error "Warning: Error in renderFunc: argument "name" is missing, with no default" after resetting the plot, and this error "Warning: Error in eval: attempt to apply non-function"  just by clicking on the "show code" without generating any output

Comment: Okay, well ... I still think `tryCatch` is what you need to make sure whatever portion fails is handled appropriately, allowing your shiny app to keep working.